# Android get view of fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity, let's call it `A`, and it launches a fragment like so:

```
remoteFragment = new RemoteFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frameLayout_remote_activity, remoteFragment)
        .commit();
```

my `remoteFragment` looks something like this:

```
public Button okBtn;

public RemoteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote, container, false);
    okBtn= view.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);

    return view;
}

public RemoteLayoutView getOkBtn() {
    return okBtn;
}
```

and in my activity I am trying to get it like so:

```
Button okBtnMessageNotWorking = remoteFragment.getOkBtn();
```

but `okBtnMessageNotWorking` is always null.

my question is how can I get the view objects from the fragment inside my activity?

Comment: Logically there is no limit to do that. Maybe you are calling `getOkBtn` before the fragment's view gets created.

Comment: Try making your button and method static

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are trying to find the view from `layoutOnTopScrollview`. Instead you should find the `okBtn` from inflated view. Please change code as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote, container, false);
    okBtn= view.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);

    return view;
}
```

Also, make sure that you are calling this method once the fragment is created.

Comment: please see my edited code. I had a mistake in the question