# Android Studio Kotlin variables

Tags: android, kotlin

ok, brand new to android studio and kotlin (not programming in general)

installed Android Studio, set up a couple of hardware profiles (and enabled dev mode).
Here is my issue:

Simple app, 'every time you click the button, the number above doubles.'

in the first_fragment.xml file, I rename the ID to 'textDisplayedValue'
in the MainActivity.kt file, I create 2 variables originalValue and newValue.

When I try to set the originalValue to the value in textDisplayedValue, I get an 'Unresolved reference' error

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euAip.png)

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oceMY.png)

In addition, when I launch the debugger, the 'ok' button is disabled.  I assume that is due to the code errors so correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDisplayedValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textDisplayedValue" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
       binding.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val originalValue = 1
            val newValue = originalValue * 2
            textDisplayedValue = newValue.toString()

            Snackbar.make(view, "Value $originalValue changed to $newValue", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you want `binding.textDisplayedValue`, but without the layout file and Kotlin source in text (not images), it is difficult to be certain.

Comment: You are trying to access a fragment view from the activity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406558/android-get-view-of-fragment-in-activity
It's hard to help you without the code.

Comment: ok, I think I have the relevant code displayed

Comment: @CommonsWare

When I type binding.textDisplayValue, it throws an error 'Unresolved reference textDisplayedValud'

Comment: if I remove the textDisplayValue variable from the MainActivity.kt file, the app runs.

Comment: Your `binding` has a `fab` in it, but the layout file you posted does not. So evidently, you have two different layout files in play. Each layout file should have its own binding property if you're using view binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Comment the not working code
2. From the toolbar select
   A. Build -> clean project
   B. After that Build -> rebuild project
3. Uncomment the not working code and do this

```
val originalValue = binding.textDisplayedValue. text() .toString().toLong()
val newValue = originalValue * 2
```

Comment: when I type 'binding.' the intellisense shows options but as soon as I type 'text' it displays the 'unresolved reference text' error

Comment: may be you are inflating the wrong layout check your bindings if it reference to the same layout that includes `textDisplayedValue`